# Adding fireplace doors with ornamental tile surround

Tags: fireplace

I am interested in adding fireplace doors (and a fireplace back) to this existing open wood burning fireplace. The flue is too narrow to fit a wood burning insert, but we'd like to regain efficiency and keep wood as a viable fuel.

Some models of fireplace doors specify the minimum/maximum opening dimensions and the finished product dimensions. The problem is no model seems to fit perfectly *over* the tile so as to hide their appearance, nor does any model fit *within* the tile without leaving gaps of approximately 1/2" on either side. How should I fit a set of doors within this fireplace opening?

[image]

Comment: Keep shopping or have one made to your specifications. What else can we say?

Answer (score 1):

You can go the smaller route and fill in the gaps will filler material (metal) with insulation or stove gasket rope behind it.

Comment: When you cover it be sure it has a viable source of fresh air otherwise it can become a real problem and dangerous as well.